# Will Android 4.4.3 allow for an Android phone to become an iBeacon?

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

Now that Android 4.4.3 has been release it includes support for peripheral mode for devices.  Does this allow for any Android device with 4.4.3 and Bluetooth LE to become an iBeacon.

If so, are there any libraries that support this?  Are any in the works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, 4.4.3 simply a bug fix release without a new revision of the Android SDK.  Cross you fingers for a new SDK with Bluetooth LE peripheral mode support, which might be released at Google I/O in late June 2014.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Fingers crossed for Google IO.  If such a thing were possible it would really help people get started with iBeacon more easily and quickly.  Also, loving your library! :)